# Get the Currency type on header click in a table, using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

This is my code, while this is working fine while sorting the currency column, I am using the replace function. But according to my code, the currency pattern will differ according to country. For that this replace is not right one.
Anyone please help me with this?

Using the normal html table.

---

```
var comparer = function (idx, asc) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return function (v1, v2) {
            v1 = v1.replace('$', '').replace('₹', '').replace(/,/g, '');
            v2 = v2.replace('$', '').replace('₹', '').replace(/,/g, '');
            return v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
        }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    };

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('th')).forEach(function (th) {
    th.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var table = th.closest('table');
            Array.from(table.tBodies[0].querySelectorAll('tr'))
                .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
                .forEach(function (tr) { table.tBodies[0].appendChild(tr) });

    });
});
<table class="no-border" onclick="sortComparer()">
        <thead class="no-border">
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Surname</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Gender</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Class</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Costs</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

C#. ascx.cs

Backend I am using this to append my currency to the table

```
 sbBody.Append("     <td class='text-right'><strong>" + string.Format("{0:C0}", Costs) + "</strong></td>");
```

Comment: You could add your code with more context to a playground, such as jsfiddle or codepen so that others can follow you better and experience the problem faster

Comment: @gco thank you for your response, can you please check it now

Comment: yw, I can't see your playground example yet.

Comment: this is my playground, I am still in confusion about what ur trying to get.

Comment: Something like this playground here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/riPoEx